# bash ignores & for last command in loop

Tags: bash

I just wrote my first bash script to start some redis instances on a development server. While it is mostly working, the last opened redis instance is blocking the active terminal – though I have the trailing `&` sign and the other started instances aren't blocking the terminal. How would I push them all to the background?

Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash 
REDIS=(6379 6380 6381 6382 6383 6390 6391 6392 6393)
for i in "${REDIS[@]}"
do
    :
    redis-server --port $i &
done
```

Comment: The whole script still has to finish - do you run it with `./scriptname &`?

Comment: Also, typo `$` instead of `&` in the title and text, I think.

Comment: Ahh, no I don't - so this is all? Just add the trailing `&`?

Comment: Well, does it work? :)

Comment: Oh, and what is the `:` for? It doesn't do anything.

Comment: Are you actually running this with ssh, e.g. `ssh host ./scriptname` ?

Comment: Or does your script do anything more than just this loop?

Comment: No, that's all it does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your terminal is not actually blocked, your prompt just got overwritten. It's a purely cosmetic issue. Due to the way terminals work, bash doesn't know to redraw it so it looks like the command is in the foreground.

Run the script again, and blindly type `ls`<kbd>Enter</kbd>. You'll probably see that the shell responds as normal, even though you can't see the prompt.

You can alternatively just hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to get bash to redraw the prompt.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, that's interesting. Typing `ls` actually worked.  Just out of curiosity, is there something I can do in the script to redraw?

Comment: You can just redirect the server output to `/dev/null` or a log file so it doesn't compete with the shell. Alternatively, if the servers only output a bit of data when they start, you can add `sleep 3` after the loop and hope that they stop writing after less than three seconds.